# Non-existent table that actually exists?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, information-schema, aws-aurora

I've been tasked to solve a very difficult and interesting problem.

Given is a MySQL database created on the AWS-Aurora service. The MySQL version reported when connecting is 5.6.10.

We have an application that uses this database and which needs tables that have very specific naming, this can not be changed.

Our table in question is named something like `vendor_catalog_scope1`, so there are no weird characters in there or any naming conflicts.

The problem:

- when trying to list the tables with `SHOW TABLES`, it's not listed
- when attempting to execute `CREATE TABLE`, an error is returned: `SQL Error (1050): Table 'vendor_db.vendor_catalog_scope1' already exists`
- when attempting to `DROP TABLE`: `SQL Error (1051): Unknown table 'vendor_db.vendor_catalog_scope1'`

So it doesn't exist, but it can not be created because it already exists, but also it can not be dropped because it doesn't exist #rolling-eyes-weird-mysql-logic.

I've started investigating by searching the tables in `information_schema` database to see if and what I find there about it.

I've actually found it in `information_schema` mentioned in these tables:

- `INNODB_SYS_TABLES`
- `INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES`

but weirdly enough it's missing from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

---

I don't know what happened or why, I just need to solve this somehow so that we can do a proper/correct `CREATE TABLE (...)` and use it in our application.

I'm guessing starting to delete rows from the `information_schema` tables is a very bad idea and more likely to break stuff rather than fix them.

Keep in mind that, being an Amazon-Aurora service, there's no way to SSH into it and poke around the actual MySQL files and change/rename/delete them.

Is there any way we can solve this **without** dropping + re-creating the entire database?